# Flask/JS redirects to "/?" instead of the URL I give it

Tags: javascript

I have a script `main.js` that consists of the following code:

```js
function showListing() {
    var url = $("#url")[0].value

    var listingID = extractListingID(url)
    if (listingID) {
        alert(`ListingID is ${listingID}`)
        location.href = `/listing/${listingID}`
    }
}

function extractListingID(url) {
    var found = url.match(/\d{9,}/)
    if (found)
        return found[0]
}
```

I expect it to redirect to `/listing/XXX`, where `XXX` is the value returned from `extractListingID()`. However, it redirects to `/?` (e.g., `127.0.0.1:5000/?` on the debug server).

Here's the network log from the devtools:

[image: The server cancels for some reason]

The server is a locally run python/flask application that successfully returns a page when I open it directly at `https://127.0.0.1:5000/listing/XXX`.

Any idea why that happens?

Comment: The code looks good, are you sure there's no redirect on the server?

Comment: show you full code. this is possible due to things elsewhere

Comment: Check the Network tab of DevTools to see where it's actually trying to go.

Comment: or, at least show your chrome devtool "network" panel for details

Comment: use jsfiddle or any other sandbox and put all of your codes in case that we could run and find problem easily

Comment: persist, in the network panel in dev tools, all network operations and see what happens when `/listing/XXX` is accessed

Comment: added the network log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the script was called from a button that didn't have a type set. So, after pressing this button, the `showListing()` function started along with the standard submit process that interfered with it.

After setting the button to `type="button"` everything works fine.